# What is the difference between numeric(9,0) and int in POSTGRES?

Tags: postgresql

Are `NUMERIC(9,0)` and `INT` the same in Postgres?

How many bytes of data can each type store?

Background: I was using the `auto-ddl` API to apply scripts to a database while starting a Spring container. Now I am trying to generate the scripts using `liquibase` by generating the `db-changelog` for `POSTGRES` server.

Comment: Postgres [numeric types.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`NUMERIC(9, 0)` and `INT` are different types in Postgres. The important difference is in storage format.

The `numeric` type can be between 0 and 255 bytes, as needed. The type modifier `(9, 0)` has no impact on the format of saved data, it is just the limit of the maximum length.

The `INT` type has a fixed length 4 bytes.

The size of `'999999999'::numeric`:

```
postgres=# select pg_column_size('999999999'::numeric);
+----------------+
| pg_column_size |
+----------------+
|             12 |
+----------------+
(1 row)
```

*NB*: some operations on `NUMERIC` types are slower than on `INT` types. The `NUMERIC` type needs more space; it is designed for working with large numbers, or precise numbers. It is not designed as a replacement for the `INT` type.

Postgres does not translate `NUMERIC(x, 0)` to `INT` or `BIGINT`.

Comment: Did you mean precise or precious? (I like both)

Comment: @Bergi precise :), Thank you for note

Answer (score 8):

No, they are not the same.

`INT` is a 4-byte column storing integer values from -2147483648 to +2147483647.

`NUMERIC(9, 0)` is a 9- to 14-byte column storing integer values from -999999999 to 999999999.

Comment: @klin Sorry if the answer can easily be misunderstood. If you have suggestions on how to improve it with more precise language, feel free to suggest an edit.

Comment: so numeric(9,0) can store upto 9 digits and int4 can store upto 10 digit numbers. right ?

Comment: @JITHIN No. `numeric(9,0)` stores 9-decimal-digit numbers, while `int4` stores 31-bit numbers (plus a sign bit).

Comment: Then how many digits can be stored by int4 ? Since numeric(9,0) clearly states that it can store upto 9 digits I wanted to know the value for int4.

Comment: So int4 is larger type when compared with numeric(9,0) just like bigint is larger than numeric(19,0). right?

Comment: @JITHIN Yes, `int` can store more distinct values (but not all 10-digit numbers). `numeric` does take more memory though because of its dynamic length and its decimal storage format.